# How to make tabs inside stack in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to make a design like given in below image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoPas.jpg "image"

Here is my code for what is have tried uptil now

```
const NotificationTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  NotificationsActivity: NotificationsActivity,
  NotificationsList: NotificationsList,

},
{
  initialRouteName: 'NotificationsActivity',
  tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
          backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
  },
  tabBarPosition: 'top',


})
```

I have two screens for the two tabs.
Here is my drawer navigator which calls that stack

```
const memberdrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {

  Notifications : { screen: NotificationTab},
  ResetPassword : { screen: ResetPassword},

  },
  {
  gesturesEnabled: true,
    contentComponent: props => <DrawerMember {...props} />
  },
  {
        contentOptions: {


            }
  }

);
```

Here is the main container for the main naviagator of the application

```
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack)
export default AppNavigator;
```

Please help me how can i make the design given in the image? Just give me blueprint for the desing and i will make it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `MaterialTopTabNavigator` as follows by adding some `props` to it.

```
const NotificationTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  NotificationsActivity: NotificationsActivity,
  NotificationsList: NotificationsList,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'NotificationsActivity',
  tabBarOptions: {
    //use this for change the color of active tab's label. 
    activeTintColor: "red",

    //use this for change the color of inactive tabs' label.
    inactiveTintColor: "black",

    //use this for change the label styles.
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 30,
    },

    //use this for change the color of inactive tab.
    inactiveBackgroundColor: "white",

    //use this for change the style of vanigation bar.
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },

    //use this for change the style of indicator.
    indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    }
},
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
})
```

for more info, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html